# How to show my activity when the notification shade is pulled down

Tags: android

Is it possible to make my activity to foreground when the notification shade is pulled down?.
My application is a simple VoIP application. My incoming call screen activity is shown behind the notification shade if it is pulled down.  
Is there any way to hide the notification shade when my activity starts?.It happens in the case of native GSM calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide notification shade with Java's reflection code.  Otherwise, the only way to detect when notification shade is pulled down is when your app's Activity is in the foreground.  And for that you can override the `onWindowFocusChanged` method in your Activity.